# why is my delegate works only when defined as VC and not as external class?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, delegates

I have followed this [tutorail](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2015/04/27/how-to-program-an-ios-text-field-that-takes-only-numeric-input-or-specific-characters-with-a-maximum-length/) on how to restrict textField to certain length and characters set

here is my code, and yet the delegate isn't called:

VC class: this is called (verified while debugging)

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

public class InlineMainViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, MainUiDelegate {

   ...

    var nameTextVerifier = NameTextVerifier()
    @IBOutlet weak var enterName_text: UITextField!
...

override public func viewDidLoad() {
    enterName_text.delegate = nameTextVerifier
    }
```

NameTextVerifier class:

```
    import Foundation

    public class NameTextVerifier: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        public func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if string.characters.count == 0 {
                return true
            }
             let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
            let prospectiveText = (currentText as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)


                return prospectiveText.containsOnlyCharactersIn("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") &&
                    prospectiveText.characters.count <= 6
              }
    }
```

this code is never called when I type in `enterName_text`

on the other hand when I put the same `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` in the VC class and setting the VC to be the delegate

func onViewDidLoad() {
    enterName_text.delegate = self
    }

makes `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` execute

how can I check what is the problem?

Comment: where you have `func onViewDidLoad(){...}` ... do you mean to say `override func viewDidLoad(){...}` ?  Otherwise, `onViewDidLoad()` never gets called which is probably the source of your issue

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt you use TextManager in Place of NameTextVerifier

```
var nameTextVerifier = TextManager()
in place of
var nameTextVerifier = NameTextVerifier()
```